# How to determine if the sequence $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos^2n}{n(n+1)} $ is absolutely convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

How to determine if the sequence $\sum \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\cos^2n}{n(n+1)} $ is absolutely convergent? 
Don't know how to handle it with a $\cos$-function.
Hope somebody can help.

Comment: Hint: $\lvert \cos^2 n \rvert \leq 1$.

Comment: The sum should start at $n=1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\color{red}{S}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\cos^2 n}{n(n+1)}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1+\cos(2n)}{2n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{2}+\text{Re}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{e^{2in}}{2n(n+1)}$$
gives:

> $$ S = 1+\sin^2(1)\cdot\log(2\sin 1)+\frac{2-\pi}{4}\cdot\sin(2)\approx\color{red}{0.3719}.$$